# Calculate moving average of residuals iteratively in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of this form

Residual = Actual - Pred

```
       Actual    Pred   Residual
0           11     10    1
1           12     10    2
2           13     10    3
3           14     10    4
4           15     10    5
5           16     10    6
6           17     10    7
7           18     10    8
8           19     10    9
```

I want to calculate the **3 day** moving average of the residuals and *add it back* to Pred column; then **recalculate the residuals** and repeat the process for next day iteratively as shown in the df below

For eg:
For **index=3**; MA of the previous 3 day residuals will be (1+2+3)/3 = 2. We add this value to the today's prediction, which will be 12 and the **new residual** will be 14-12 = 2.

Now, for **index=4**; we take the last 3 days **MA of Residual_New** i.e. (2+3+2)/3 ~ 2.33. So Pred_new = 12.33 and Residual_New = 15-12.33 = 2.67 .. and so on

```
       Actual    Pred   Residual  Pred_New Residual_New
0           11     10    1         10        1
1           12     10    2         10        2
2           13     10    3         10        3  
3           14     10    4         10+2      2
4           15     10    5         10+2.33   2.67
5           16     10    6         ........
6           17     10    7          .......
7           18     10    8
8           19     10    9
```

How can I achieve this effectively in pandas.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're learning about integrator and double integrator terms in PID

Comment: What have you done to attempt to solve this problem? You have input, output and some requirements, but no relevant code.